# Tkinter Label Updating Issue

Tags: python, string, tkinter, label, tk-toolkit

[Python 2.7] Hello. I'm working on a simple Tkinter calculator program, but can't seem to get the label to display any text after I push one of the buttons. Here is the code I'm using, some of the button functions are unfinished until I can get the label itself working:

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import ttk
    """Calculator"""
    #Variables
    Entered = ""

    #Button Functions
    def Natural_Log():
        pass
    def Exp():
        Entered = "^"
    def Sin():
        pass
    def Cos():
        pass
    def Tan():
        pass
    def LeftParentheses():
        Entered = Entered + "("
    def RightParentheses():
        Entered = Entered + ")"
    def Log():
        pass
    def XSquared():
        Entered = Entered + "**2"
    def InvX():
        Entered = Entered + "**-1"
    def Seven():
        Entered = Entered + "7"
    def Eight():
        Entered = Entered + "8"
    def Nine():
        Entered = Entered + "9"
    def DEL():
        Entered = Entered[:1]
    def AC():
        Entered = ""
    def Four():
        Entered = Entered + "4"
    def Five():
        Entered = Entered + "5"
    def Six():
        Entered = Entered + "6"
    def Mult():
        Entered = Entered + "*"
    def Div():
        Entered = Entered + "/"
    def One():
        Entered = Entered + "1"
    def Two():
        Entered = Entered + "2"
    def Three():
        Entered = Entered + "3"
    def Plus():
        Entered = Entered + "+"
    def Minus():
        Entered = Entered + "-"
    def Zero():
        Entered = Entered + "0"
    def Decimal():
        Entered = Entered + "."
    def Ex():
        pass
    def neg():
        pass
    def EXE():
        pass


    #Main Window Setup:
    #Root setup
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Generic Calculator")

    #Parent frame setup
    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root,padding="8")
    mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=(N,S,E,W))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

    #Button setup
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="ln",command=Natural_Log).grid(column=1,row=2,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="^",command=Exp).grid(column=2,row=2,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="sin",command=Sin).grid(column=3,row=2,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="cos",command=Cos).grid(column=4,row=2,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="tan",command=Tan).grid(column=5,row=2,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="(",command=LeftParentheses).grid(column=1,row=3,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text=")",command=RightParentheses).grid(column=2,row=3,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="log",command=Log).grid(column=3,row=3,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="x^2",command=XSquared).grid(column=4,row=3,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="x^-1",command=InvX).grid(column=5,row=3,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="7",command=Seven).grid(column=1,row=4,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="8",command=Eight).grid(column=2,row=4,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="9",command=Nine).grid(column=3,row=4,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="DEL",command=DEL).grid(column=4,row=4,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="AC",command=AC).grid(column=5,row=4,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="4",command=Four).grid(column=1,row=5,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="5",command=Five).grid(column=2,row=5,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="6",command=Six).grid(column=3,row=5,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="*",command=Mult).grid(column=4,row=5,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="/",command=Div).grid(column=5,row=5,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="1",command=One).grid(column=1,row=6,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="2",command=Two).grid(column=2,row=6,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="3",command=Three).grid(column=3,row=6,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="+",command=Plus).grid(column=4,row=6,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="-",command=Minus).grid(column=5,row=6,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="0",command=Zero).grid(column=1,row=7,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text=".",command=Decimal).grid(column=2,row=7,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="EXP",command=Ex).grid(column=3,row=7,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="(-)",command=neg).grid(column=4,row=7,sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe,text="EXE",command=EXE).grid(column=5,row=7,sticky=W)

    #Label Setup:
    EnteredSetup = StringVar()
    ttk.Label(mainframe,textvariable=EnteredSetup).grid(column=1,row=1,columnspan=5)
    EnteredSetup.set(Entered)


    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a misunderstanding on how StringVar works. The line

```
EnteredSetup.set(Entered)
```

does not create some form of link between EnteredSetup and Entered, modifying Entered does not issue updates in EnteredSetup. Your code can be improved a lot too, and you should post something that is only long enough to describe the problem. Said that, consider this reduced version already fixed (note that it could be much smaller):

```
from Tkinter import Tk, StringVar
import ttk

class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

    def ac(self):
        self.state.set('')

    def state_num(self, num):
        self.state.set('%s%d' % (self.state.get(), num))

#Main Window Setup:
#Root setup
root = Tk()
root.title("Generic Calculator")

EnteredSetup = StringVar('')
calc = Calculator(EnteredSetup)

#Parent frame setup
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="8")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

#Button setup
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="AC", command=calc.ac).grid(
        column=5, row=4)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="1", command=lambda: calc.state_num(1)).grid(
        column=1, row=6)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="0", command=lambda: calc.state_num(0)).grid(
        column=1, row=7)

#Label Setup:
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=EnteredSetup).grid(
        column=1,row=1,columnspan=5)

root.mainloop()
```

I hope this guides you in the right direction for further adjusting your calculator.